# Using regex for dividing a substrings by comma based on repeating groups

Tags: regex, python-3.x

This is a coding exercise. I'm supposed parse html to a string using python such that a string of html like the following:

```
"<div><p><b></b></p><p></p><p></p></div>"
```

Becomes:

```
"DIV([P([B([])]),P([]),P([])])"
```

Where each global tag that encloses other ones have to be returned separated by a comma.

I understand that regex is not the best choice for this kind of job. Nevertheless, I have a limited set of tools available of which regex is one of them.

So far, what I have is the following:

```
repl_from = ["<div>", "</div>", "<img />", "<p>", "</p>", "<b>", "</b>"]
for i in repl_from:
    if i == "<div>":
        j = "DIV(["
    elif i == "<img />":
        j = "IMG({})"
    elif i == "<p>":
        j = "P(["
    elif i == "<b>":
        j = "B(["
    else: j = "])"
    html = html.replace(i, j)
```

This gets me `DIV([P([B([])])P([])P([])])`. Now I have to divide the inner arguments by commas, and this where I thought about using regexes. But I'm lost in this regards.

I have a seudo code that goes something like this:

1) Find the opening of a global tag (`patternI = '[A-Z]+\(\[)'`)

2) Check if what follows are repeating tags (`patternII = '[A-Z]+\(\[\]\)+'`)

3)If so, get start and end index of `patternII`, and then just do a replace with the commas. This last part can be simply executed by splitting using the `split()` and later the `join()`function, I think.

How can I implement the last part of the algorithm?

**EDIT**

Ok, I think I made a mistake when explaining the situation. For any tag that encloses another set of tags (like `<div><p></p><p></p></div>`) the enclosed tags must be parsed as arguments to the global one (therefore: `DIV([P([]), P([])])`); if the global tag encloses only one, then there are no commas added (`<div><p></p></div>` will turn out to be `DIV([P([])]`). In the case when there's no enclosed tag (like so `<p></p><b></b>`) then when they are transformed, then they carry no commas in between (as such `P([])B([])`).

Comment: I think you may be barking up the wrong tree with this approach. The trick is to keep a list of all the read tags by appending new opening tags and removing them when they close. You'll then be able to work out when you need to add the commas. The task is about creating a LIFO stack.

Comment: I thought about that approach but I didnt know how to keep account of the open and closing brackets. Can you suggest a replacement method?

Comment: LIFO stands for last in first out. Each time you append a tag it's open, each time you remove one it's closed. So if a tag is open and another tag opens the  the new one will have to close first. Have a think about it, jot it down on paper or something you'll see.

Comment: Well, thanks for taking the time out to point that particular way. I'm gonna try to implement something of the sort but, again, I'm having problems doing it.

Comment: Use function recursion, it's that simple.

Comment: @sln I'm sorry, I'm not clear as to how to do that. That's why I'm asking, unfortunately.

Comment: Function recursion is a programming technique. If you are new to programming, perhaps Google it will solve your problem.

Comment: @sln Listen, thanks for taking the time for answering. I know what you are referring to, but I don't know how to implement it. Again, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure I am not understanding something here but if this is the case why not just use a simple:

```
a="DIV([P([B([])])P([])P([])])"
import re
print(re.sub(r"\)[A-Z]","),P",a))
```

This will give:

```
'DIV([P([B([])]),P([]),P([])])'
```

**I must apologise for the fact that I don't know html at all so I can only try to match what you come up with as value of "a"(since I can't imagine all the possible cases that may exist) in regards to your recent comment:**

lest say:

```
a="DIV([P([B([])])P([])B([])])P([])B([])"
```

This we can fix with a mix of `re.findall` and `re.sub`:

first we will find all that we want to replace in a:

```
b=re.findall(r"\)[A-Z]",a)
print(b)
```

this will give:

```
[')P', ')B', ')P', ')B']
```

after that we will need to insert a comma in belween each element as we will use this to substitute the original elements:

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i]=b[i][0]+","+b[i][1]

print(b)
```

this will give:

```
['),P', '),B', '),P', '),B']
```

then we will use this b to substitute :

```
for i in range(len(b)):
    a=re.sub(r"\)[A-Z]",b[i],a,1)

print(a)
```

which will give:

```
DIV([P([B([])]),P([]),B([])]),P([]),B([])
```

so the entire above code will look like:

```
import re

a="DIV([P([B([])])P([])B([])])P([])B([])"
b=re.findall(r"\)[A-Z]",a)

for i in range(len(b)):
    b[i]=b[i][0]+","+b[i][1]


for i in range(len(b)):
    a=re.sub(r"\)[A-Z]",b[i],a,1)

print(a)
```

P.S.: please just share the possible values of a for which it won't work and the final result you expect from that. I will be able to match it for that.

Comment: I think this wont work for a case like `<p></p><p></p>` because the output should be `P([])P([])`. Its because whatever is inside a tag has to be parsed like arguments to a function in the output. I think I didnt make this clear in the orginal question.

Comment: I am sorry but I think it will work with this expression`P([])P([])`, kindly run it and check and please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Ok, I think I made a mistake when explaining the situation. For any tag that encloses another set of tags (like `<div><p></p><p></p></div>`) the enclosed tags must be parsed as arguments to the global one (as such: `DIV([P([]), P([])])`); if the global tag encloses only one, then there are no commas added (`<div><p></p></div>` will turn out to be `DIV([P([])])`. In the case when there's no enclosed tag (like so `<p></p><b></b>`) then when they are transformed, then they carry no commas in between (as such `P([])B([])`). So your solution doesn't apply for the case I'm talking about.